# How to extract Android APK package version_name using python?

Tags: java, android, python

Currently I'm using androguard (https://github.com/androguard/androguard) but it takes too much time in reading the package and extracting the version_name. Is there another way to extract the version_name of a apk file with python or any faster way of doing it with androguard.
Also, (if any) faster way to do it via java will also help (please elaborate the steps as I have no knowledge of java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In place of using androguard, you can use pyaxmlparser available here https://github.com/appknox/pyaxmlparser. You can directly run it on python and extract all the data like package name, version name and much more. It is fast and you will be able to extract data of around 30 apps per minute.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have access to AAPT (standard android sdk built-tool), the following should give you the information.

```
aapt dump badging myApk.apk | grep versionName
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use grep and you want to seek through the massive dump of data on your own, just use `aapt dump badging myApk.apk` and traverse the string until you find the info you're looking for.

Using SDK 27.0.3, the following is the return of the above command with grep:

```
package: name='com.example.myapk' versionCode='49' versionName='1.2.3' platformBuildVersionName=''
```

---

For executing this command in python, use the subprocess module:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html